# How to update a QtabWidget by index after an event in a QMainWindow?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

In my application (which has a QTabWidget in the QMainWindows) I would like the tab to update at a given time, is it possible ?
I post part of the code in the main.
I hope you can help me.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = APSC_GUI()
    #"""
    # On liste le contenu du répertoire temporaire ...
    liste_contenu_tmp = os.listdir(tempfile.gettempdir())
    # Boucle de vérification ...
    for contenu in liste_contenu_tmp :
        # Si le fichier tempo concerné est bien 
        # dans le répertoire temporaire ...
        if 'data_fin_traitement_apsc' in contenu :
            # ------------------------------------------------------- #
            # Utilisation de la classe Tempo_lecture pour la lecture
            # des données dans le répertoire (dit) temporaire
            # ------------------------------------------------------- #
            rep_tempo_lecture = Tempo_lecture(tempfile.gettempdir(), os.getcwd(), 'data_fin_traitement_apsc_', 'data_fin_traitement_apsc')
            # ... avec appel de la méthode affichage
            rep_tempo_aff = rep_tempo_lecture.affichage()[0]
            # Si les fichier temporaire a bien été crée à la
            # fermeture de la fenêtre 
            if rep_tempo_aff == '1' :
                ex.tab_widget.setCurrentIndex(3)
    #"""
    ex.show()
    ...
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What does *the tab to update* mean? What part of the tabwidget do you want to update?

Comment: If you want to call the `foo_function` after `t` milliseconds you must use `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(t, foo_function)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but that's not what I ask. In fact I have an interface (the main script) in which there is a QTabWidget, the different tabs of the QTabWidgets each display different widgets when they are selected (QPushButton, QRadioButton, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QComboBox, ... QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView).
The application starts automatically with the tab at index 0 selected, this is normal operation ...

Comment: ...
At the end of the processing (it is started by a QPushButton) the result is displayed in a tab dedicated to the visualization (located at index 3).
At the end of each treatment, a text file (containing '1') is written to the temporary directory. I would like that at the end of each treatment, the tab at index 3 is automatically selected ... after opening the text file (whose content is '1').
I do not know if my explanation is very clear. I can explain it more clearly with screenshots of my application if it can be more convenient.

Comment: Call to `your_tabwidget.setCurrentIndex(3)` when you want to change the tab. if that does not work then you must provide a [mcve] since the problem is probably causing another part of the code you are hiding.